# Daily correlation coefficients - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have Data1(43200 rows , includes NaNs) and Data2 (43200 rows,includes NaNs) which are both 1-min data for a given month of 30 days. Now i want to calculate correlation i.e. [R,p] of Data1 and Data2 for every day, that is i should have 30 R and p values.
Can someone please help
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. SSR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
d1 = reshape(Data1,[1440,30]);
d2 = reshape(Data2,[1440,30]);
res = zeros(30,2);
for day = 1:30
   dailyData = [d1(:,day);d2(:,day)];
   dailyData(any(isnan(dailyData),2),:) = []; %removes rows with nan
   [R,p] = corr( dailyData );
   res(day,1) = R; res(day,2) = p; 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am getting all NaN's as R and p because my Data1 and Data2 has Nan's in it at different locations.

Comment: Do you have statistics toolbox?

Comment: Just posted an answer with explicit removal of NaN (like here http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/data_analysis/missing-data.html?searchHighlight=remove%20nan). Also, in stat toolbox you can use nancov, nanvar, but it doesn't give you p-values

Comment: Thanks fr your kind help. I had to do a slight change in the code though because my almost every row had atleast one Nan, so removing rows with NaN command left me with an empty matrix. I converted NaN to -999.9999.. My question is will the correlation be affected because of -999.9999 in the data? .. Many thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, your correlation values are affected by the imputations. It's probably better to replace NaN by the interpolated values (e.g., take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628957/matlab-using-interpolation-to-replace-missing-values-nan?rq=1)